# Speakers not firing at max volume

Tags: volume-control, speakers

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have Mivi Play Bluetooth speakers connected in stereo. They are connecting to the laptop without any problem but the speakers are firing only at around 30-40% volume even when I max out the volume of my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Many Bluetooth speakers often have their own volume control (as yours does), independent of your actual PC's volume control.

It's unclear whether you've set your *laptop's* or your *speaker's* volume to maximum, but in order to get the loudest possible audio, you should ensure that *both* the speaker and laptop volume are set to maximum.

If you only want to mess around with one volume control in the future, I usually just set my speaker's volume to maximum and control the overall volume using my PC.

Comment: Good answer. I didn't think to suggest checking the hardware.